# How to maintain a collection based on Models in PHP?

Tags: php, list, observablecollection

I'm having a Model, the Model Class contains some Property. Based on the Model, I need to save the details.

For Ex:
Model Class Name : `MobileInfo`

- Mobile Brand
- List of `MobileModelInfo`
- Mobile OS

Sub Model Class Name : `MobileModelInfo`

- Brand
- Category
- Year of Launch

Here Mobile Info is Collection of Properties, I need a list of MobileInfo in php as like ObservableCollection in C#

Comment: It is very unclear to me what you are trying to do. If you are just after a code translation service, Stack Overflow is not the place for it.

Comment: You want us to translate code from C# to php? We don't do that here, sorry.

Comment: Store it in an array?

Comment: @Lock - Can you please showcase your code.